# io.Pipe() not working as desired. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: go, kubernetes, exec, client-go

I have been testing exec functionality to a kubernetes pod with client-go. This is the code that works perfectly with os.Stdin

```
{
    // Prepare the API URL used to execute another process within the Pod.  In
    // this case, we'll run a remote shell.
    req := coreclient.RESTClient().
        Post().
        Namespace(pod.Namespace).
        Resource("pods").
        Name(pod.Name).
        SubResource("exec").
        VersionedParams(&corev1.PodExecOptions{
            Container: pod.Spec.Containers[0].Name,
            Command:   []string{"/bin/sh"},
            Stdin:     true,
            Stdout:    true,
            Stderr:    true,
            TTY:       true,
        }, scheme.ParameterCodec)

    exec, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(restconfig, "POST", req.URL())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Put the terminal into raw mode to prevent it echoing characters twice.
    oldState, err := terminal.MakeRaw(0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer terminal.Restore(0, oldState)

    // Connect this process' std{in,out,err} to the remote shell process.
    err = exec.Stream(remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdin:  os.Stdin,
        Stdout: os.Stdout,
        Stderr: os.Stderr,
        Tty:    true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println()
}
```

I then started to test with a io.Pipe() so that I can give it input apart from the os.Stdin, basically from a variable or any other source. The modified code can be found here

```
{
    // Prepare the API URL used to execute another process within the Pod.  In
    // this case, we'll run a remote shell.
    req := coreclient.RESTClient().
        Post().
        Namespace(pod.Namespace).
        Resource("pods").
        Name(pod.Name).
        SubResource("exec").
        VersionedParams(&corev1.PodExecOptions{
            Container: pod.Spec.Containers[0].Name,
            Command:   []string{"/bin/sh"},
            Stdin:     true,
            Stdout:    true,
            Stderr:    true,
            TTY:       true,
        }, scheme.ParameterCodec)

    exec, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(restconfig, "POST", req.URL())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Put the terminal into raw mode to prevent it echoing characters twice.
    oldState, err := terminal.MakeRaw(0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer terminal.Restore(0, oldState)

    // Scanning for inputs from os.stdin
    stdin, putStdin := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        consolescanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        for consolescanner.Scan() {
            input := consolescanner.Text()
            fmt.Println("input:", input)
            putStdin.Write([]byte(input))
        }
        if err := consolescanner.Err(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }()

    // Connect this process' std{in,out,err} to the remote shell process.
    err = exec.Stream(remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdin:  stdin,
        Stdout: os.Stdout,
        Stderr: os.Stdout,
        Tty:    true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println()
}
```

This oddly seems to be hanging the terminal, can someone point me out on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code is too much to consume - it would be better if you could provide a more minimal producible code, but from a glance, I think by using `bufio.Scanner` and `putStdin.Write`, you are removing line breaks (`\n`) from the input.

Comment: @leafbebop I've edited the part of the code that matters to make it minimal. Does this help now? To answer your later statement, im not intending to remove the line breaks, I want to extend the os.stdin using io.pipe()

Comment: Have you tried to add the line breaks back?

Comment: @leafbebop Yes I did try that but it did not help. The issue is that whatever I type in STDIN is not being reflected in the variable anymore.

Comment: what variable do you mean? you can't print it?

Comment: What kind of buffering behavior do you intend for the `consolescanner` goroutine? Do you want it to always prompt for input immediately and buffer all of the inputs in RAM, or wait for the previous input to be forwarded, or something else?

Comment: So the my use-case is to fetch the inputs immediately from os.Stdin, and pipe them to a `io.Pipe()` or `os.Pipe()`(like its suggested below). The reader interface of the pipe will be an input to the stream, so that the stream would be getting wtever I type in my stdin immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue. Unfortunately, none of the above methods helped me but rather I did the below work.
I created a separate `io.Reader` for the string I wanted to input, then did a `io.Copy` from the reader to `putStdin` from the above code snipper. Earlier I used `putStdin.Write(<string>)` which did not do the trick.

I hope this solves issues for some folks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try to understand all of your code, but: when executing a separate process, you pretty much always want to use `os.Pipe`, not `io.Pipe`.

`os.Pipe` is a pipe created by the operating system.  `io.Pipe` is a software construct that lives entirely in Go that copies from an `io.Writer` to an `io.Reader`.  Using an `io.Pipe` when executing a separate process will generally be implemented by creating an `os.Pipe` and starting up goroutines to copy between the `io.Pipe` and the `os.Pipe`.  Just use an `os.Pipe`.

Comment: The use case here is a bit complex, I would want to fetch some information from os.Stdin of a go program A, stream the input to a go program B and pass that as an input to the remote shell from program B. Thus I end up using `io.Pipe` in program B, do you suggest a better solution here?

Comment: I suggest that where you write `io.PIpe`, you write `os.PIpe`.  That is, stop using `io.Pipe` entirely.  Use `os.Pipe` instead.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Thanks @bcmills for reminding me that the buffer of `os.Pipe` is system dependent.

Let's re-look at os.Pipe() return values

```
reader, writer, err := os.Pipe()
```

To resolve that, we should have a `MAX_WRITE_SIZE` constant for the length of the byte array written to the `writer`.

The value of `MAX_WRITE_SIZE` should be system-dependent also. For example, in linux, the buffer size is 64k. So we can configure `MAX_WRITE_SIZE` to a value < 64k.

If length of the data to send is greater than `MAX_WRITE_SIZE`, it can be broken in chunks to send sequentially.

---

The reason the terminal hang is because of deadlock when you use `io.Pipe()`.

Document on the `io.Pipe()` method

> Pipe creates a synchronous in-memory pipe.

> The data is copied directly from the Write to the corresponding Read (or Reads); there is no internal buffering.

So writing to Pipe when there is no pipe read call blocking will cause deadlock (similar to reading from Pipe when there is no pipe write call blocking)

To solve the issue, you should use `os.Pipe`, which is similar to linux [pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) command.

Because the data will be buffered, so no read/write blocking is required.

> Data written to the write end of
> the pipe is buffered by the kernel until it is read from the read
> end of the pipe

Comment: > Because the data will be buffered, so no read/write blocking is required.

The amount of buffering in an `os.Pipe` is system-dependent, so the code patterns that deadlock for `io.Pipe` are not guaranteed to work for `os.Pipe` either.

Comment: @bcmills thank you. I will update my answer to warn OP about setting a max size for the write pipe

Comment: @TranvuXuannhat In my case I am reading from os.Stdin, scanning the values and writing to the pipe. Just to be clear, buffering the variable `input` from the second code block to `MAX_WRITE_SIZE` will fix the locking issue?